# issue with spring webflux stream in spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

I have custom spring cloud data flow source application which connects to a rest end point and buffer the data and send to a custom sink . I am using Spring webflux for the same. Everything works fine if i do a block() and collect all the data available and send the same to the message Channel .The issue is  i need  to send the data in chunks and hence buffer the data in stream say chunks of 100K records and send to the Message Channel .Now when i try to do the buffer and send the chunks to the messaging channel its  failing .

> Working Code (Blocking call to collect all data and send at once)

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(
    value = Source.OUTPUT
    poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "120000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "100000")
public  MessageSource<List<MyDataDTO>> sendEdpiMessageToChannel() {
List<MyDataDTO> list=WebClient.create()
    .get()
    .uri(builder -> builder.scheme("https")
    .host("server_name")
    .path("/api/endpoint")                  
    .build())
    .header("Cookie",cookie)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchange()
    .flatMapMany(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToFlux(MyDataDTO.class))      
    .collectList()
    .block();                      
 return ()->MessageBuilder.withPayload(list).build();
}
```

> Now i want to buffer the same and send it instead of doing a collect
>   and blocking call but this is failing
>
> SOURCE CODE

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 120000)
public  MessageSource<List<MyDataDTO>> sendEdpiMessageToChannel() {
List<MyDataDTO> list=WebClient.create()
    .get()
    .uri(builder -> builder.scheme("https")
    .host("server_name")
    .path("/api/endpoint")                  
    .build())
    .header("Cookie",cookie)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchange()
    .flatMapMany(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToFlux(MyDataDTO.class))//.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())              
    .buffer(100000)
    .concatMap(streamRecordsList -> Mono.fromRunnable(()->sendToChannel(streamRecordsList));
}

@InboundChannelAdapter(
    value = Source.OUTPUT
)
public MessageSource<List<MyDataDTO>> sendToChannel(List<MyDataDTO> list ) 
{
    return ()->MessageBuilder.withPayload(list).build();
}
```

> STACK  TRACE

2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-09-16 06:27:47.859 ERROR 9 --- [ scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to invoke method; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:117)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:160)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:360)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:329)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:274)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:230)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:114)
2019-09-16T02:27:47.860-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 18 more
2019-09-16T02:27:48.533-04:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Container became healthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with below code

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 120000)
public  MessageSource<List<MyDataDTO>> sendEdpiMessageToChannel() {
List<MyDataDTO> list=WebClient.create()
    .get()
    .uri(builder -> builder.scheme("https")
    .host("server_name")
    .path("/api/endpoint")                  
    .build())
    .header("Cookie",cookie)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchange()
    .flatMapMany(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToFlux(MyDataDTO.class))//.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())              
    .buffer(100000)
    .concatMap(streamRecordsList -> Mono.fromRunnable(()->sendToChannel(streamRecordsList));
}

public void sendToChannel(List<MyDataDTO> list ) 
{
   this.source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(list).build());
}
```